# Can i get warehouse_id from location_id in odoo 10,11

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

Is it possible to get `warehouse_id` from `location_id` in odoo.
thanks.

Comment: Please describe more .

Comment: Nice quotes on your profile by the way :)@MrRobot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Odoo 10 and 11

```py
location = self.env['stock.location'].browse(1)  # or any other location
warehouse = location.get_warehouse()
```

Code for [get_warehouse()](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7a1db7e62033ca0236d829ae3e60303875c85ce1/addons/stock/models/stock_location.py#L104)

```py
@api.multi
@api.returns('stock.warehouse', lambda value: value.id)
def get_warehouse(self):
    """ Returns warehouse id of warehouse that contains location """
    return self.env['stock.warehouse'].search([
        ('view_location_id.parent_left', '<=', self.parent_left),
        ('view_location_id.parent_right', '>=', self.parent_left)], limit=1)
```